# Convergence of Sequence Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have just learned about the convergence of a sequence with the epsilon definition.

So when we try to prove a limit of the sequence, what are we doing essentially (with respect to the definition)?

For example, if we want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/\sqrt{n} = 0,$$
then we want to show, by definition, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M$ such that whenever $n\geq M$, $|a_n - 0| < \varepsilon$, in other words our $n^\text{th}$ term ($a_n$) should be less than $\varepsilon$. So we want to prove this last statement?

So is this correct: we want $a_n <\varepsilon$ to be true, so $1/\sqrt{n} <\varepsilon$, or $n > 1/\varepsilon^2$. In other words, we have that $M > 1/\varepsilon^2$ ? So to show this limit is indeed true, we want to be able to show the inequality is true or that we want to show we can always this $M$ by choosing its construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your last statement is closest. We want to show that for every $\varepsilon$, it is possible to find the appropriate $M$ such that. Showing that this is possible by construction of $M$ is usually a good way to go.

Comment: so my question is, when starting on these problems, one would focus on the inequality and "work backwards"  to find what M is ?

Comment: Yes, that is usually the best way to go.

Comment: OK so this is how my book proves it: let epsilon > 0 be an arbitrary positive number. Choose a natural number satisfying M > 1/epsilon^2. We now verify that this chocie of M has the desired property. Let n >= M. Then, n > 1/epsilon^2 implies 1/sqrt(n) < epsilon and hence |a_n - 0| < epsilon

Comment: So my question is, after finding the construction for M, this allows us to ultimately conclude the inequality that we wished to show true? In other words, we can manipulate the construction and show the inequality?

Comment: Exactly. In your proof, you don't need to show how you got $M$, you only have to show that the choice you made gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

You have to show, that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists M: |a_n-a|<\varepsilon \ \forall n\geq M  $.

So your argumentation is correct up to this point. And you are done because $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrarily choosen and you have found an $M$. So the proof is done. 
You only have to show existence and that is what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea.

We want, for any choice of $\epsilon$, to be able to find an $M$ such that the inequality holds. The process you worked through (i.e. taking $M > \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$) gives us a way to find/construct our $M$ in such a way that it works for any $\epsilon$ we like.

The proof lies in being able to find an $M$ for any $\epsilon$, and in essence, that is what you have done.